# Return dataframe with columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a function to calculate Heikin Ashi candles (for financial analysis).
My indicators.py file looks like

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
def heikinashi(dataframe):

    open = dataframe['open']
    high = dataframe['high']
    low = dataframe['low']
    close = dataframe['close']

    ha_close = 0.25 * (open + high + low + close)
    ha_open = 0.5 * (open.shift(1) + close.shift(1))
    ha_low = max(high, ha_open, ha_close)
    ha_high = min(low, ha_open, ha_close)

    return dataframe, ha_close, ha_open, ha_low, ha_high
```

And in my main script i'm trying to call this function the most effective way to return those four dataframes: ha_close, ha_open, ha_low and ha_high

My main script looks something like:

```
import indicators as ata
ha_close, ha_open, ha_low, ha_high = ata.heikinashi(dataframe)

dataframe['ha_close'] = ha_close(dataframe)
dataframe['ha_open'] = ha_open(dataframe)
dataframe['ha_low'] = ha_low(dataframe)
dataframe['ha_high'] = ha_high(dataframe)
```

but for some strange reason I cannot find the dataframes
What will be the most efficient way to perform this? code wise and with minimal calls

I expect to have dataframe['ha_close'] etc returned with the correct data as shown in the function

Any advice appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should remove `dataframe` from the return statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "find the dataframes"? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

In `heikinashi()` you are returning five elements, `dataframe` and `ha_*`, however, in your main script you are only assigning the return values to four variables.

Try changing the main script to:

```py
dataframe, ha_close, ha_open, ha_low, ha_high = ata.heikinashi(dataframe)
```

Apart from that, it looks like `dataframe` which you are passing into `heikinashi()` is not defined anywhere.